# Data not being updated after put request with Axios | React, Reduxforms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form, axios

Hello people of Stack Overlflow! I have a problem that I can't solve and I need your help.

**My Problem**: After I've sent a put request to the server nothing changes. I'm console.logging this inside of my backend `console.log(ctx.request.body)` and it is the same data as before the put request. Although I'm getting `Status Code:200 OK` in the network tab.

So, I have a form that should be able to update the data from the API. And inside of my form I have an `onSubmit` handler:

```
  onSubmit={e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    onSubmit(id, item)
  }}
```

Here I am calling my function handleSubmit and passing id and item. Id is the id of the object and item is the object itself.

And here's the component that uses the `onSubmit`:

```
class DoorSettingsContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DoorSettingsForm
          onSubmit={this.props.updateSettings}
          item={this.props.location.state.item}
          id={this.props.location.state.item._id}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    item: state.settings.item
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    updateSettings: (id, value) => dispatch(updateSettings(id, value))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(
  DoorSettingsContainer
)
```

And here's my action that handles the put request:

```
export function updateSettings(id, item) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: 'SETTINGS_IS_LOADING' })
    console.log(dispatch)
    console.log('FÖRE', item)
    axios
      .put(`${settings.hostname}/locks/${id}`, item)
      .then(() => {
        console.log(item)
        dispatch({
          type: 'SETTINGS_UPDATED',
          payload: {
            item,
            id
          }
        })
        console.log('EFTER', item) // It's still the same
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
}
```

And finally, my snippet from my backend:

```
r.put('/' + key + '/:id', async (ctx, next) => {
  console.log(key) // Outputs locks
  console.log(ctx.request.body) // Same as before
  await ctx.db
    .collection(key)
    .replaceOne({ _id: objectId(ctx.params.id) }, ctx.request.body)
  ctx.body = { _id: ctx.params.id }
})
```

So my problem is that my put request wont work to 100%. Is it might because I'm using Redux forms? Or is my backend not configured to 100%?

Thanks for all the help!